# Matlab Coder array size restriction

Tags: c, arrays, matlab

I am working with large data in large arrays with Matlab. My program runs fine and now I have converted it to C but am hit with a maximum array size issue.

When the `emxArray` is defined, it is defined as follows:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
    double *data;
    int *size;
    int allocatedSize;
    int numDimensions;
    boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

The problem here being that the variable `size` is an `int` (not even a `uint32`) so the max array size I can have in the C code is 2^31. This is a problem. I am operating on data with array sizes over 1E9.

Is there any way I can tell Matlab to use a `long` or a `long long` or some unsigned datatype to represent the size? I found the following page but I am just hoping there is some way to fix this other than saying it won't work:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/array-size-restrictions-for-code-generation.html

Comment: @AlexQuilliam *"I have to convert it **to** C"*. Chris: that documentation seems to answer your question quite clearly, in favour of your undesired conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it, as the documentation, you linked, explains.

So i see some workaround:

- Matlab should be efficient on handling huge array, so use Matlab,
- export the array to a file, handle in c, export from c and import back in Matlab. (or with database and some triggers).
- on the function which calls C: split the array and sent it in chunks.